# SiteMapPath Asp.net at Java

Tags: java, asp.net, breadcrumbs, sitemappath

how can i do SiteMapPath navigation like Asp.net at Java 
(home -> product -> dvd -> ...)
Exist some lib or jar to do it ? Or some example, would be nice, any idea )

Thank you.

Thank you CraigTP :)

Answer (score 0):

This will very much depend upon the java web framework that you're using.
What you are essentially looking for is a "*Breadcrumb*" component or code.

The following links should get you started:

Custom JSP Tag/Servlet: [Breadcrumbs taglib](http://coldjava.hypermart.net/servlets/navtag.htm)
Wicket:  [BreadCrumbBar Class](http://www.wicketframework.org/wicket-extensions/apidocs/wicket/extensions/breadcrumb/BreadCrumbBar.html)
Struts2:  [Breadcrumbs Plugin](http://cwiki.apache.org/S2PLUGINS/breadcrumbs-plugin.html)